# Ininite launch application android Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, launch, infinite

I'm stuck with a huge problem. When I start an application, the progress bar in the "Progress" views in eclipse is stuck at 100% and the apps never starts. I can't cancel the startup and I have to kill Eclipse's process.
Java return me an exit code : -805306369. I saw nothing on google about my problem ...
About java version, it is jdk1.7.0_03.

Answer (score 1):

`java7` is not compitable for android so use `java6` is better...

So,in

**Eclipse ->Window->Prefrences->Java->Compiler->Complier Compliance level->1.6->Hit OK**

Comment: I downloaded jdk6 here : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u32-downloads-1594644.html and I changed the compliance level and the problem is the same ...